# Axios upload progress for PUT request in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, axios

I'm using axios to upload a file via a PUT request. Is there a way to show upload progress to the user while upload is ongoing. I tried `onUploadPregress` in config but it only works in the browser not in the node runtime.

If not axios then maybe I'll have to figure out a way to do it using the default `http` API that node offers.

Answer (score 2):

[`got`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/got) is a nice HTTP client for NodeJS and it has a [progress event](https://www.npmjs.com/package/got#onuploadprogress-progress) as well.